# Character Strings related : string_units db cfg changed from SYSTEM to CODEUNITS32

Tags: db2, db2-luw, unicode, db2-10.5

To handle few special characters, we changed `string_units` database configuration parameter from default `SYSTEM` to `CODEUNITS32`.

Based on IBM [DB2 Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc/doc/r0060936.html), there are three methods to achieve this.

1.Set the `NLS_STRING_UNITS` global variable

2.Update the `string_units` database configuration parameter

3. Alter the column by defining new character set ( `CODEUNITS16` or `CODEUNITS32`)

We have used the second option and restarted the instance. Still it's not working as expected. Have we missed any steps?

Is the reorg required on the table? What happens to the already existing data ?

db2level - 10.5 fp5
OS : Windows

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE <schema>.<tabname> ALTER COLUMN <colname> SET DATA TYPE VARCHAR(20 CODEUNITS32);
```

The alter column set data type with `CODEUNITS32` clause did the job.
If the `string_units` database configuration parameter is set to `CODEUNITS32`,
any new table without specifying this clause in column definition still works.

We have to perform the above alter only to the columns of existing table which was defined when string_units was set to default `SYSTEM`.

Hope it helps to other users.

Comment: The db cfg STRING_UNITS is how things should be interpreted if not declared explicitly. Since STRING_UNITS where SYSTEM when the table where created you will have to alter the table like you did if you would like it to be CODEUNITS32. You can check SYSCAT.COLUMNS.TYPESTRINGUNITS to find out what is used for a particular column. Also, if CODEUNITS32 is a special case and you normally use SYSTEM, you may want to change the db cfg to SYSTEM. Otherwise all new columns will become CODEUNITS32 unless you specify them as OCTET.